# Capturing *all* terminal output of a program called from Python

Tags: python

I have a program which can be execute as

```
./install.sh
```

This install bunch of stuff and has quite a lot of activity happening on screen..

Now, I am trying to execute it via

```
p = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

With the hope that all the activity happening on the screen is captured in `out` (or `err`). However, content is printed directly to the terminal while the process is running, and not captured into `out` or `err`, which are both empty after the process is run.

What could be happening here? How can this content be captured?

Comment: Why do you think you were wrong? (It's possible for a program to bypass this kind of capture by using `/dev/tty` instead of stdout and stderr, but few do).

Comment: The above output should work. Another mechanism would be to use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: What you have looks (to me) like it should work... I suppose without knowing more about the executable and how you're running it, it's really hard to give any advice here...

Comment: You could call `os.setsid()` to detach from your controlling terminal if you think the process is connecting to `/dev/tty` directly.

Comment: @Fraz, are you also checking the output of `print err`? Also, are you sure that your program emits any output at all when it detects that stdout isn't connected directly to a terminal? (It's not uncommon for software to detect this case and behave differently).

Comment: If the content were truly going straight to your Python program's stdout/stderr (_or_ its controlling TTY) rather than being captured, you'd have the content printed as soon as you called `communicate()` rather than going into a variable. From your comments, it sounds like this isn't happening, meaning that the problem is _not_ related to a capture failure.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So when I run the program, I see the stdout on the terminal.. but that stdout on terminal is not via print out statement but via the normal output generated by that shell script

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer with all the code needed to demonstrate the problem? Right now, this is something nobody can see but you -- and if I run the code you provided with a `executable` that I write myself that writes to stdout and stderr, it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer yet included a workaround with `script` (that didn't have side effects such as duplicating output) when you awarded it the check, but it's in a somewhat better state now than it was previously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, what you're doing is already sufficient to channel all output to your variables.

One exception to that is if the program you're running is using `/dev/tty` to connect directly to its controlling terminal, and emitting output through that terminal rather than through stdout (FD 1) and stderr (FD 2). This is commonly done for security-sensitive IO such as password prompts, but rarely seen otherwise.

---

As a demonstration that this works, you can copy-and-paste the following into a Python shell exactly as given:

```
import subprocess
executable = ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2']
p = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print "---"
print "output: ", out
print "stderr: ", err
```

...by contrast, for a demonstration of the case that *doesn't* work:

```
import subprocess
executable = ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'echo uncapturable >/dev/tty']
p = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print "---"
print "output: ", out
```

In this case, content is written to the TTY directly, not to stdout or stderr. This content cannot be captured without using a program (such as `script` or `expect`) that provides a fake TTY. So, to use `script`:

```
import subprocess
executable = ['script', '-q', '/dev/null',
              '/bin/sh', '-c', 'echo uncapturable >/dev/tty']
p = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print "---"
print "output: ", out
```